# Homebrew and usr/local/include/ question

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I am trying to install python3 with homebrew and I would like to know if I can delete these files.
After running brew doctor, I get this message:

Unexpected header files:

```
/usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
/usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
/usr/local/include/node/node.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
/usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
/usr/local/include/node/smalloc.h
/usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
/usr/local/include/node/tree.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
/usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
```

Can EVERY single one of these files be deleted?

Comment: Looks like you installed node so if not through Homebrew then might be OK. (which is why you should a package manager in its own path :))

Comment: Thanks Mark, but how could I have installed node when I have NO idea what node is? Could it have been installed automatically without my knowledge along with another program?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I found this comment. 4 years later, all I use is Node.js and javascript. I'm also a software engineer. Crazy how time flies and people grow. I had no clue what I was doing back then. Man.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. Homebrew will re-load any files it needs next time you install or update or have an error compiling a package.

To be safe, make a backup of the Mac - Time Machine is fine for this. Things in /usr/local aren't from OS X so you won't cause system issues removing these files.

```
brew rm node
```

The above command should clean up node.js and you could re-install it after cleaning up if you need it.

Comment: Does that clear up node if not installed via Homebrew?

Comment: @Mark no - deleting things by hand is a poor cleanup option and the `brew rm node` only would clean up a `brew` based installation. I added it since the OP found the issues from `brew doctor` - I'm also counting on that backup in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Doesn't brew doctor only report things brew did not install?

Comment: @mark no. It checks for anything that can cause packages to fail whether it's internal or external to the tool.

Comment: @bmike running brew rm node returns a "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node" error. Should I just delete these files from the usr bin and then empty trash?

Comment: Yes. It looks like brew is going to need a manual deletion intervention. Sorry @55Cancri

Comment: Thanks. I used these commands to completely remove node: sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /Users/$USER/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
brew install node